# How to inject model in root app module in nest js app

Tags: typescript, jwt, nestjs

Hello i got an error in my nest app here is the screenshot of error:

[image]

Here is the code of app module:

```
@Module({
  imports: [AppModule,CrudModule,MongooseModule.forRoot("mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb"),AuthModule,UsersModule,MulterModule.register({
    dest:'./uploads',
  })],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService,AuthService,UsersService,JwtService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Here is the code of model:

```
export interface credentials extends mongoose.Document{
    email:String,
    password:String
}
```

Here is the code of UsersServices:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
//import {logindto} from 'src/crud/DTO/login.dto'
import {credentials, studentmodel} from 'src/crud/crud.model'
import {model,Model} from 'mongoose'
import {InjectModel} from '@nestjs/mongoose'
//export type User = any;

@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
 constructor(@InjectModel('credentials')private readonly credentials:Model<credentials> ) {}
  //constructor(@InjectModel('student')private readonly credentials:Model<studentmodel> ){}

  async findByEmail(username: string): Promise<any> {
    return await this.credentials.findOne({
        where: {
            email: username,
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: The error says nestjs cant resolve dependencies for your `UsersService`. Post the code of the service

Comment: code added.Question updated

Answer (score 1):

try adding
`MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'credentials', schema: credentials }])` to the import section of the AppModule.

Architecture-wise User services and Authentication should be encapsulated in their own modules.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what kaznovac said, you need to remove your `AppModule` from the `imports` array. Also, as it looks like you already have a `UsersModule` you should remove any providers that the `UsersModule` provides from the `AppModule`'s `providers` array. Otherwise, Nest will try to make instantiations of those providers again.

Comment: i have one CrudModule which is used for CRUD API's.One is root module that is AppModule where i did mongo db connectivity.By following yours method i got error of, Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the CrudService (?). Please make sure that the argument studentModel at index [0] is available in the CrudModule context

Comment: Well, any providers you make use of **inside a module** need to also be imported **in that same module**. This is a cornerstone of NestJS. So you can  either add the `CrudModule` to the `imports` array of `UsersModule`, or you can make the `CrudModule` `@Global()`, just make sure you know what you're doing.